# Выбор из SQL базы данных записей с последней датой и предпоследней датой

Tags: sql, sql-server

пробую через SELECT

```
SELECT nmId, MAX(date_c) FROM hour_prices
```

Но столбец date_c вычисляемый и выдает ошибку.

Будет ли работать MAX(date_c)-1 как предпоследние значения.

Возможно есть более простой способ.

Comment: Даты у вас уникальные в таблице? Т.е. на одна строка - это одна дата? Тогда возможно имеет смысл отсротировать выборку по дате по убыванию и сделать limit - чтобы вернуло только две первые строки.

Comment: нет даты не уникальные. много записей с одинаковой датой

Comment: Тогда подзапрос с LIMIT даст 2 последние даты, а по ним выберешь записи

Comment: а ошибка у вас кстати возникает не потому что столбец вычисляемый, а потому что вы используете групповую функцию и при этом хотите еще получить колонку nmId вот какое значение вы в этой колонке хотите, если запрос по сути собирает все строки таблицы в одну

Comment: а можно пример с кодом ) спс

Comment: ошибка возникала так как в названии (о боже) был символ кириллицы вместо англ, соответственно он и не находил столбец. спс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM hour_prices WHERE date_c=(SELECT MAX(date_c) FROM hour_prices)` - вывод всей информации из строк с самой поздней датой

`SELECT * FROM hour_prices WHERE date_c=(SELECT MAX(date_c) FROM hour_prices WHERE BDATE NOT IN (SELECT MAX(date_c) FROM hour_prices))` - вывод всей информации из строк с предпоследней датой

`SELECT MAX(date_c) FROM hour_prices` - находим позднюю дату

`SELECT MAX(date_c) FROM hour_prices WHERE date_c NOT IN (SELECT MAX(date_c) FROM hour_prices)` - ищем позднюю дату среди всех дат, за исключением самой поздней - то есть ищем предпоследнюю дату